# Not recognising numbers

Tags: rasa, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

Hi I have built a simple chatbot to answer a story. It is not in English (so please bear with me)

This is the NLU I wrote to recognise phone number:
[image]

This is a custom action which prints user input:
[image]

Domain:

[image]

My issue is that the phone number is not recognised like other values such as account number and amount. I use same regex for all, but still not working. How can I overcome this issue:
[image]

As you can see it returns `None` for phone number. But other values are correctly filled.

Comment: Does your `config.yml` have a RegexEntityExtractor attached? Does your `domain.yml` file have a definition for this entity too? That may be your culprit. 

In the future: please refrain from posting screenshots of code. It may be easy to share for you, but it's incredibly hard to debug when one cannot copy/paste.

Comment: I had RegexFeaturizer. Then I switched to RegexEntityExtractor, but it behaved rather different. For example instead of recognising phone, it recognised account number. I know that both phone and account can be confused as same with regex, but still the example answers I gave Rasa didn't work???. So after I again switched to RegexFeaturizer, but now it works. I don't know why it didn't before (I haven't changed any config before and after). In rasa forums they stated that sometimes the training is inconsistent and therefore these problems occur.

Comment: sorry for the photos. I was desperate for a quick answer. . Here is my github: https://github.com/ahrooran-r/chatbot-tamil-rasa.git   Please state anything I missed. This is just a first project for me in Rasa

Comment: If you're really desperate for a quick answer I might especially urge you to not send screenshots. Screenshots cannot be copied, pasted or searched/found.